# How to change the format of my list here?

Tags: python, list

Here I have a list like this.

```
["['2021-07-08']", "['2021-08-06,2021-07-25']"]
```

I want to convert the list into this format.

```
['2021-07-08', '2021-08-06,2021-07-25']
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: There is "ast.literal_eval" to evaluate a string which contains a representation of a Python data structure (like a list) as the actual object. Then you can retrieve the string item in each list and place it in another list.

Comment: You have to use List comprehension, Regular Expression and Capture Grouping.. May be use "re" module

Comment: It is hard to be sure without context, but this *looks* like one of those cases where it might be beneficial to take a step back and try to avoid getting into the mess in the first place. Of course, sometimes we just have to live with the data we get...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the list items have list items erroneously. Definitely a better idea to avoid getting the list into that 'format' in the first place rather than cleaning it up downstream. If possible, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ast`:

```
import ast,itertools
l=["['2021-07-08']", "['2021-08-06,2021-07-25']"]
l2=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([ast.literal_eval(j) for j in l]))
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some fancier matching, regexes, maybe `map`, but a more old-fashioned way:

```
def stripper():
    old_list = ["['2021-07-08']", "['2021-08-06,2021-07-25']"]
    new_list = []
    for item in old_list:
        item = item.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\'', '')
        new_list.append(item)
    print('using loop: '+str(new_list))

def strip_func(item):
    item = item.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\'', '')
    return item

def stripper2():
    old_list = ["['2021-07-08']", "['2021-08-06,2021-07-25']"]
    new_list = list(map(strip_func, old_list))
    print('using map: '+str(new_list))


stripper()
stripper2()
```

output:

```
using loop: ['2021-07-08', '2021-08-06,2021-07-25']
using map: ['2021-07-08', '2021-08-06,2021-07-25']
```

*Edit: Included map method. No imports necessary, tightened a repetitive transformation.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution without using ast. You can use the strip method like so:

```py
arr = ["['2021-07-08']", "['2021-08-06,2021-07-25']"]
targetArr = []

for i in arr:
    targetArr.append((i.strip("[]\'")))

print(targetArr)
```

which returns the required array

```
['2021-07-08', '2021-08-06,2021-07-25']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do string manipulations and get your data using `rstrip()` and `lstrip()`

```
s = ["['2021-07-08']", "['2021-08-06,2021-07-25']"]
res = []
for i in s:
    temp = i.rstrip("]\'").lstrip("\'[")
    res.append(temp)
    

print(res)
```

```
['2021-07-08', '2021-08-06,2021-07-25']
```